# ContentNegotiationConfigurer ot finding acceptable representation?

Tags: json, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a `REST` webservice that can take a `format=xml/json` parameter for different output.

Base on this official example:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
           .favorPathExtension(false)
           .favorParameter(true)
            .parameterName("format")
            .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
            .useJaf(false)
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

Result:

When using `format=json` everyting works fine. When using `format=xml`, an error page is displayed saying: `Could not find acceptable representation`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add response object class you are trying to serialize in the question. Your spring controller's method also. thanks. I have an idea what is wrong but i want to be sure

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had an inner static class that was missing the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation. Json worked without, but not xml. I didn't know it would behave differently.

Comment: yeah, my idea was that you are missing some of the jaxb xml annotation in the class you are trying to serialize ;)